# Couldn't drop staging_database : #<PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, ssl

For a system that I am using, I run into the problem pasted on the title when I try to drop a database and recreate it. More specifically, this is the exact problem that I am facing:

`Couldn't drop staging_databse : #<PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host xxx.xx.xxxx.xxx, user "ruby", database "postgres", SSL off`

I've done some research regarding this problem and it seems that the solution is simply to turn on SSL. I've consulted Postgresql Documentation on pg_hba.conf but I'm unable to find this configuration file.

I typed in locate postgresql and I noticed that there is a postgresql-client-9.2 installed on the system. From what I have determined, I won't find this pg_hba.conf file because the client doesn't have it. I've also looked for the postgresql.conf file on SSL according to the official documentation but this file is not included either.

Finally, the documentation shows me this configuration option of the pgsql 9.2 client shown below:

```
libpq reads the system-wide OpenSSL configuration file. By default, 
this file is named openssl.cnf and is located in the directory reported by 
openssl version -d. This default can be overridden by setting environment 
variable OPENSSL_CONF to the name of the desired configuration file.
```

However, this too isn't in my system. I've run the linux find command and this file doesn't seem to be there. I've run out of leagues and I have a sneaking suspicion that I am overlooking something very simple. Is there any other leads I can go on? Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting to a local instance of postgres or a remote one?

Comment: _pg_hba.conf but I'm unable to find this configuration file_: log in as database superuser and issue `show hba_file;` in psql.

Comment: Thanks @DanielVérité for the comment. I wasn't able to connect as the database super user. When you get the chance can you take a look at this seperate but related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725922/could-someone-explain-what-postgresql-client-is-and-how-it-interacts-with-postgr

Comment: @Skram thanks for your reply too. Do you think that you could also take a look at this question that I posted. I think I am connected to a remote database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725922/could-someone-explain-what-postgresql-client-is-and-how-it-interacts-with-postgr

Comment: The db being local or remote is key to your problem, and it's perplexing that you're not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this message and the rest of the context:

> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host xxx.xx.xxxx.xxx, user "ruby", database "postgres", SSL off

It looks plausible that:

- you're connecting to a remote PostgreSQL instance which you don't administrate because you're acting as developer, not admin.
- the db management layer tries to connect to the database named `postgres` in order to drop another database (`staging_database`) . It's necessary indeed because we can't drop a database when we're connected to it (in fact, a database can't be dropped when anyone is connected to it).
- the admin policy established by the remote `pg_hba.conf` is such that your login and IP address together are not allowed to connect to the database named `postgres`

These facts combined together imply that you're missing the necessary rights to drop your database, even if indirectly.

At this point you want to submit the problem to the admin responsible for that PostgreSQL server.