# Could someone explain what postgresql-client is and how it interacts with postgresql core package?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am having a database related issue illustrated by a previous question found here. [Could'nt drop staging database. PG::CONNECTION Fatal. no pg_hba.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693266/couldnt-drop-staging-database-pgconnectionbad-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf). What it comes down to is that I need to figure out how to turn on SSL in order to drop and recreate a database.

While trying to troubleshoot this process, I've discovered a few kinks in my system that require an explanation because I currently don't understand how I'm able to perform some operations. This is what I'm experiencing.

Currently, I am able to run a rails c, script/console (The system I'm working with is Rails 2.3) and I'm able to grab entries from a database. This would indicate that postgresql is installed. The error that states that the connection was fatal confirms it. When I try to login as a database super user, I get this error:

```
The program 'postgres' is currently not installed. To run 'postgres' please ask your  
administrator to install the package 'postgres-xc'
```

Running a `locate postgresql` command reveals that I have this package installed.

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-client-9.2
```

It also seems that I actually do have postgresql installed as shown by this snippet of output.

```
/usr/lib/postgresql
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/clusterdb
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/createdb
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/createlang
/usr/lib
```

Now, when I try to `sudo apt-get install postgres-xc` I get a message stating that the postgresql-client will be removed. What is going on here?

Ultimately, I want to find the pg_hba.conf file so I can turn on SSL. Do I have the postgresql9.2 installed or not? If its not installed why does the locate postgresql command show that it is? If its not, then what is postgresql-client-9.2? What does it do? The documentation only states this:

```
 postgresql-client-9.2 - client libraries and client binaries
```

What does this mean? I just want to know because at my work place, I'm supposed to have the client installed but in order to download postgres-xc I need to remove the client. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing so I can make the best decision possible. Any input would be helpful thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to install Postgres-XC? That is something completely different than PostgreSQL. `clusterdb` `createdb` and `createlang` are in fact **client** side Postgres tools. They are wrappers around the SQL statements `cluster`, `create database` and `create language`. "*Ultimately, I want to find the pg_hba.conf*" - you will **only** find that on a server installation because it controls the connectivity *on the server* and is part of the **server** configuration. You will never have that on the client side

Comment: I wanted to install postgres-XC because of a recommendation from another question from a user that said to find the pg_hba.conf by signing in as a super user. It seems that if I understand you correctly, I need to find the server that has the actual postgresql package installed and change the pg_hba.conf file there.

Comment: You most probably do not want Postgres-XC. I have no idea why that (stupid IMHO) recommendation is there. If you can connect to the local server as the superuser (typically `postgres`), then you can query the location of the pg_hba.conf by checking the `pg_settings` view.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name. I finally found it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's an Ubuntu bug, IIRC. Dan, what exact Ubuntu / Debian version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL command line client program is `psql`.

`postgres` is the *server* program.